# Asset pipeline Configuration for Rails 4. Can someone explain why my Rails 4 has no sprocket-rails gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've read on the ruby on rails guide, that the asset pipeline is a thing of the past and that starting with rails 4, assets will be handled by the sprockets-rails gem. That's great and all but here's my problem. This is the internals of a rails app I've made.

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.0'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more:    
https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background.     
Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development
```

As you can see, I'm using rails 4.1 but there is no sprocket-rails gem. I'm just curious why this is. Everything works fine but I'd like to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sprocket-rails` gem is one of the *runtime dependencies* of `rails` gem.
You can check it on **[RubyGems site: Rails Runtime Dependencies](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails#runtime_dependencies)**

This means that when you run `bundle install` command, `bundler` not only installs the gems listed in `Gemfile` but it also fetches all remote sources, resolves dependencies and installs all needed gems.

Bottom-line is that `bundler` will take care of the runtime dependencies, you can even check those in your `Gemfile.lock`(Just search for `rails (4.1.0)` in the `Gemfile.lock`).

Refer to the documentation of **[bundle-install command (mainly DESCRIPTION section)](http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/bundle-install.1.html)**